# Python JSON String to tabular formatting

Tags: python, mysql, json, csv, tabular

The script at the bottom of the post helps me fetch and re-orient the data from JSON into a list of info like shown directly below...

I need to restructure this into tabular format for either CSV conversion, or better yet do a MySQL INSERT after its been restructured to X over Y axis's, however the current JSON output has re-occurring headers that are not needed in a conversion to table, so I'm really just trying to strip the response of say "first_name" and "last_name" values, and have this as column headers while the values are denoted in rows.

Not super savvy yet with Python, but I feel its the most sensible way to handle the processing, any help appreciated!

```
id , 9999999
first_name , Joe
last_name , Schmo
group_id , 99999
active , True
employee_number , 0
salaried , False
exempt , False
username , jschmo
email , abc123@gmail.com
email_verified , False
payroll_id ,
mobile_number , 9999999999
hire_date , 0000-00-00
term_date , 0000-00-00
last_modified , 2021-02-08T01:59:42+00:00
last_active , 2021-02-10T22:45:34+00:00
created , 2021-02-04T20:07:38+00:00
client_url , abcefg
company_name , Some Company Name
profile_image_url , https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/000000000000000000000000000
display_name ,
pronouns ,
pto_balances,
1400406 , 0
submitted_to , 2021-02-08
approved_to , 2021-02-08
manager_of_group_ids , []
require_password_change , False
pay_rate , 0
pay_interval , hour
permissions,
admin , False
mobile , True
status_box , False
reports , False
manage_timesheets , False
manage_authorization , False
manage_users , False
manage_my_timesheets , False
manage_jobcodes , False
pin_login , True
approve_timesheets , False
manage_schedules , False
external_access , False
manage_my_schedule , False
manage_company_schedules , False
view_company_schedules , False
view_group_schedules , False
manage_no_schedules , False
view_my_schedules , False
view_projects , False
manage_projects , False
time_tracking , True
customfields ,
id , 1111111
first_name , Jane
last_name , Doe
group_id , 11111
active , True
employee_number , 0
salaried , False
exempt , False
username , jdoe
email , xyz789@gmail.com
email_verified , False
payroll_id ,
mobile_number , 111111111
hire_date , 0000-00-00
term_date , 0000-00-00
last_modified , 2021-02-08T01:59:42+00:00
last_active , 2021-02-10T22:45:34+00:00
created , 2021-02-04T20:07:38+00:00
client_url , abcefg
company_name , Some Company Name
profile_image_url , https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/000000000000000000000000000
display_name ,
pronouns ,
pto_balances,
1400406 , 0
submitted_to , 2021-02-08
approved_to , 2021-02-08
manager_of_group_ids , []
require_password_change , False
pay_rate , 0
pay_interval , hour
permissions,
admin , False
mobile , True
status_box , False
reports , False
manage_timesheets , False
manage_authorization , False
manage_users , False
manage_my_timesheets , False
manage_jobcodes , False
pin_login , True
approve_timesheets , False
manage_schedules , False
external_access , False
manage_my_schedule , False
manage_company_schedules , False
view_company_schedules , False
view_group_schedules , False
manage_no_schedules , False
view_my_schedules , False
view_projects , False
manage_projects , False
time_tracking , True
customfields ,
```

```
import requests
import json
import csv



url = "https://rest.apiofsomesort.com/api/v1/users"

payload = ""
headers = {
   'Authorization': "Bearer                ",
  }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

#print(response.text)

# Saves response to JSON file
emp_data = response.json()
with open('emp_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(emp_data, f)

# Loads from JSON file while iterating recursively through nested keys,values
with open('emp_data.json','r') as string:
    my_dict=json.load(string)
string.close()
def iterate_emp_data(my_dict):
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        if(isinstance(v,dict)):
            print(k+",")
            iterate_emp_data(v)
            continue
        print(k+" , "+str(v))
iterate_emp_data(my_dict)
```

Comment: you should do `some_list.append([k, v])` instead of `print()` and then you can write it without big changes in data. Or use two lists `headers.append(k)`, `values.append(v)`. If you don't want some values then use `if/else` to skip them before adding to lists.

Comment: That was actually another question I had was the better means to reuse the processed results for either further processing, or file output, will try this for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting the dictionary my_dict into a pandas DataFrame.

or, instead of your current function, if you are look to pool multiple rows:
Data = dict()

```
def iterate_emp_data(my_dict):
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        if(isinstance(v,dict)):
            Data[k.strip()].append(v)
```

and then put it in a dataframe

Comment: Yeah I've tried Pandas more than a few different ways with this situation, I've tried normalizing with Pandas after the string is oriented into a list but I'm not a veteran yet with data refining, however I'll try your tip and see what it yields, thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to get first names and last names?  Because if you already have a dictionary, why not just take the data  you need and store it? ```my_dict['first_name']``

Comment: You're right, its along the lines of what I'm trying to achieve, but most anything I've tried is based on semi-similar examples, or how-to's. I'm not familiar with how to store certain results from the dictionary where if after I can achieve this, the preferred output would be a mysql insert, however output to CSV works fine too since I know how to load a mysql table from either python or mysql LOAD DATA INFILE

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the problem..

```
import requests
import json
import time




url = "https://rest.apiofsomesort.com/api/v1/users"

payload = ""
headers = {
   'Authorization': "Bearer ",
  }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

#print(response.text)

# Saves response to JSON file
emp_data = response.json()
with open('emp_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(emp_data, f)

time.sleep(2)
data = json.load(open('emp_data.json'))
jtopy=json.dumps(data) #json.dumps take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.
dict_json=json.loads(jtopy) # json.loads take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
print(dict_json["results"]["users"]["9999999"])
```

The above code simplifies plucking results for just one employee from the JSON API response.

Because the JSON structure has employee's laid out like so -->

```
{"results": {"users": {"9999999": {"id": 9999999, "first_name": "Joe"} "9999998": {"id": 9999998, "first_name": "Destiny"}
```

The problem, isn't defining a dictionary for known "keys" such as "first_name", "last_name", "username", etc... however, because the user id value is also used as a unique key per each employee record, I get an error like this

```
KeyError: 'first_name'
```

if I try and run something like this

```
print(dict_json["results"]["users"]["first_name"])
```

because the JSON is structured like this..

```
{"results": {"users": {"9999999": {"id":9999999, "first_name": "Joe"} "9999998": {"id": 9999998, "first_name":
```

I do have success parsing just the results for a single employee's first name using this.

```
print(my_dict["results"]["users"]["9999999"]["first_name"])
```

or I can pull everything from the API response (all employees, all details, etc)
using

```
print(my_dict["results"]["users"]
```

I've tried to iterate the API response in hopes re-orienting the data provides better chances of plucking the key values that lye after each unique employee id-key `{"9999999":` but haven't had any luck watering down a ton of info that isn't easily coverted into tabular format for CSV, or MySQL insertion.

Answer (score 0):

To give further insight as to the API/examples of the JSON, here's an example of the output from the API response

```
{
  "results": {
    "users": {
      "933849": {
        "id": 933849,
        "first_name": "Mary",
        "last_name": "Samsonite",
        "group_id": 0,
        "active": true,
        "employee_number": 0,
        "salaried": false,
        "exempt": false,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@example.com",
        "email_verified": false,
        "payroll_id": "",
        "mobile_number": "2087231456",
        "hire_date": "0000-00-00",
        "term_date": "0000-00-00",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-28T17:24:20+00:00",
        "last_active": "",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:34+00:00",
        "client_url": "api_sample_output",
        "company_name": "API Sample Output Company",
        "profile_image_url": "https:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61",
        "display_name": "",
        "pronouns": "",
        "pto_balances": {
          "2624351": 0,
          "2624353": 0,
          "2624355": 0
        },
        "submitted_to": "2000-01-01",
        "approved_to": "2000-01-01",
        "manager_of_group_ids": [ ],
        "require_password_change": false,
        "pay_rate": 0,
        "pay_interval": "hour",
        "permissions": {
          "admin": true,
          "mobile": true,
          "status_box": false,
          "reports": false,
          "manage_timesheets": false,
          "manage_authorization": false,
          "manage_users": false,
          "manage_my_timesheets": false,
          "manage_jobcodes": false,
          "pin_login": false,
          "approve_timesheets": false,
          "manage_schedules": false,
          "external_access": false,
          "manage_my_schedule": false,
          "manage_company_schedules": false,
          "view_company_schedules": false,
          "view_group_schedules": false,
          "manage_no_schedules": false,
          "view_my_schedules": false,
          "time_tracking": false
        },
        "customfields": ""
      },
      "933845": {
        "id": 933845,
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "group_id": 64965,
        "active": true,
        "employee_number": 0,
        "salaried": false,
        "exempt": false,
        "username": "bobsmith",
        "email": "",
        "email_verified": false,
        "payroll_id": "",
        "hire_date": "0000-00-00",
        "term_date": "0000-00-00",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-27T16:13:33+00:00",
        "last_active": "2018-03-28T20:16:39+00:00",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:33+00:00",
        "client_url": "api_sample_output",
        "company_name": "API Sample Output Company",
        "profile_image_url": "",
        "display_name": "",
        "pronouns": "",
        "mobile_number": "",
        "pto_balances": {
          "2624351": 0,
          "2624353": 0,
          "2624355": 0
        },
        "submitted_to": "2000-01-01",
        "approved_to": "2000-01-01",
        "manager_of_group_ids": [ ],
        "require_password_change": false,
        "pay_rate": 0,
        "pay_interval": "hour",
        "permissions": {
          "admin": false,
          "mobile": true,
          "status_box": false,
          "reports": false,
          "manage_timesheets": false,
          "manage_authorization": false,
          "manage_users": false,
          "manage_my_timesheets": false,
          "manage_jobcodes": false,
          "pin_login": false,
          "approve_timesheets": false,
          "manage_schedules": false,
          "external_access": false,
          "manage_my_schedule": false,
          "manage_company_schedules": false,
          "view_company_schedules": false,
          "view_group_schedules": false,
          "manage_no_schedules": false,
          "view_my_schedules": false,
          "time_tracking": false
        },
        "customfields": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "more": false,
  "supplemental_data": {
    "jobcodes": {
      "2624351": {
        "id": 2624351,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "assigned_to_all": true,
        "billable": false,
        "active": true,
        "type": "pto",
        "has_children": false,
        "billable_rate": 0,
        "short_code": "",
        "name": "Sick",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "filtered_customfielditems": "",
        "required_customfields": [ ],
        "locations": [ ]
      },
      "2624353": {
        "id": 2624353,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "assigned_to_all": true,
        "billable": false,
        "active": true,
        "type": "pto",
        "has_children": false,
        "billable_rate": 0,
        "short_code": "",
        "name": "Vacation",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "filtered_customfielditems": "",
        "required_customfields": [ ],
        "locations": [ ]
      },
      "2624355": {
        "id": 2624355,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "assigned_to_all": true,
        "billable": false,
        "active": true,
        "type": "pto",
        "has_children": false,
        "billable_rate": 0,
        "short_code": "",
        "name": "Holiday",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:28+00:00",
        "filtered_customfielditems": "",
        "required_customfields": [ ],
        "locations": [ ]
      }
    },
    "groups": {
      "64965": {
        "id": 64965,
        "active": true,
        "name": "Construction",
        "last_modified": "2018-03-27T16:13:30+00:00",
        "created": "2018-03-27T16:13:29+00:00",
        "manager_ids": [
          "933833"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```